# Making given y-axis data in dB?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I learned recently how to draw in pgfplots and is really enjoying the output. I generate my data in matlab and then write it to a file. One line of the file will contain two entries, first x-axis data and then corresponding y-axis data. Now I realize, I actually want the y-axis data to be in dB , i.e. whatever current values are in that file, I want 'x' against '10*log(y)' where logarithm is base 10. But, now I can't go back to matlab and generate all this data again. So I have to do it within pgfplots. Is this possible?

For a MWE, this is the data I have in a file by name fig1-line1.dat

```
0   0.095529
1   0.12026
2   0.1514
3   0.19061
4   0.23996
5   0.30209
6   0.38031
7   0.47878
8   0.60275
9   0.75882
10  0.95529
```

This is my current code which plots it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shapes,shadows,fit,calc}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri]
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}% <-- moves axis labels near ticklabels (respects tick label widths)
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}



\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={legend pos = north west},legend cell align = {left}}

\pgfplotsset{%
tick label style={font=\normalsize},
title style={font=\normalsize,align=center},
label style={font=\normalsize,align=center},
legend style={font=\normalsize}
            }

\begin{axis}[%
xlabel = {Iterations},
ylabel = {Relative Error in Convergence $\epsilon_i$},
title  = {Convergence Rate v/s Iterations},
enlargelimits = true,
cycle list name = {color},
grid = major,
smooth,
scale = 1]

\addlegendentry{$K=2$, $M=3$}

\addplot [ color = {blue}, 
           mark  = {o},
           style = {solid},
           line width = 2pt] table {fig1-line1.dat};



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A larger example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

So the current plot is 'x' against 'y'. Now I want to make it 'x' against '10*log(y)'? How do I do this?

Comment: Set `ymode=log` in the `axis` options

Comment: hello jake, will it make it $10*log()$?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough. `ymode=log` will not work in this case. You'll have to transform your data. I added an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can transform your data using `y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{10*log10(\pgfmathresult))}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{10*log10(\pgfmathresult)}}
]
\addplot table {
0   0.095529
1   0.12026
2   0.1514
3   0.19061
4   0.23996
5   0.30209
6   0.38031
7   0.47878
8   0.60275
9   0.75882
10  0.95529           
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you have 10 but decibels have 20 as a factor but you can modify it as you wish.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={legend pos = north west},legend cell align = {left}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
log basis y=10,
yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{20*(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfmathresult}},
xlabel = {Iterations},
ylabel = {Relative Error in Convergence $\epsilon_i$ [dB]},
title  = {Convergence Rate v/s Iterations},
enlargelimits = true,
cycle list name = {color},
grid = major,
smooth,
scale = 1]
\addlegendentry{$K=2$, $M=3$}

\addplot [ color = {blue}, 
           mark  = {o},
           style = {solid},
           line width = 2pt] table {
0   0.095529
1   0.12026
2   0.1514
3   0.19061
4   0.23996
5   0.30209
6   0.38031
7   0.47878
8   0.60275
9   0.75882
10  0.95529
};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: where do I change $20$ to $10$?

Comment: @dineshdileep in yticklabel options but then remove the [dB] from the ylabel too.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel . For me, its a ratio of powers.

Comment: @dineshdileep Well, well I didn't know they have different versions of dB. It's strange I have never come across those conventions though I'm using db scale daily with 20log10 for 10+ years because I work mainly of power ratios. I guess I should never take things for granted.